# Is there a way to convert SWF animations to movie files on Linux?

Tags: linux, conversion, file-format, swf

Is there any Linux tool that will take a SWF file and output some kind of video format?  Note that I don't want a tool which will re-encode an embedded FLV or MP4, I want to take a standard Flash movie and render it as a video.

I found a reference to `dump-gnash` in the [GNU Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/manual/gnashuser.html), but having installed the gnash package on Fedora I don't have that command.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Have you seen [ConvertSWF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/convertswf/files/ConvertSWF/)? untested but you need dump-gnash.

Answer (score 1):

While not the best option, you could try compiling gnash yourself and passing the `--enable-gui=dump` flag.

To do this, I downloaded the latest gnash from http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gnash/0.8.10/

1. Extract with `tar -xf gnash-0.8.10.tar.gz`
2. Change into the extracted directory `cd gnash-0.8.10`
3. Run `./configure --enable-gui=dump`
4. Run `make`

But to do this, you will need basic development tools (GCC, GNU Make) and some libraries like FFMPEG, boost and agg (but you can install these from your distribution, no need to compile yourself, otherwise you would be compiling for a while).
I may have left a few libraries out, but `./configure` should tell you if you are missing something.

You can then run `./gui/dump-gnash [options] movie_file.swf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use edit.py:

```
apt-get install pyvnc2swf
apt-file search edit.py
pyvnc2swf: /usr/share/pyvnc2swf/edit.py
```

Then convert it by outputing:

> /usr/share/pyvnc2swf/edit.py -o
>   output.flv original.swf

Then if you need to convert it once more to another format use ffmpeg (can convert to many popular video format):

```
ffmpeg -i output.flv output.avi
```

Comment: Unfortunately I just end up with a seven minute long movie of complete blackness :(  BTW, the Fedora equivalent command is `vnc2swf-edit`

Comment: Sorry to hear, guess it's Debian only? Works on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: I got it installed fine, it just didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try playing the file and recording your screen at the same time, although there are probably a lot better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Should you still have the .fla file, try publishing the swf for Flash 9. I had a sequence I wanted to convert into a video to no avail when using newer Flash swf formats. But it went well with Flash 9 compatible swfs and edit.py!

Comment: I never at any point had the original .fla.  Nor do I have a version of Flash which works on Linux.